# Why gesture recognizer outlets are strong by default

Tags: ios

When you create an outlet for a control by Ctrl-dragging in Interface Builder it usually suggests to make the outlet weak.

But if you create an outlet for a gesture recognizer the suggestion is to make it strong.  I am curious what is the reason behind of this, what is wrong with making gesture recognizer outlets weak too?

Comment: This is very strange: I would expect it to be weak, because views retain their gesture recognizers the same way that they retain their subviews.

Comment: ref:http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5126
From ios 5.0 it does not retain the gesture recognizers when added to a view controller, By making strong properties and connecting them to the gesture recognizers, you can ensure that they stay alive otherwise the app will crash.

Comment: @prasad Why didn't you post this as an answer? It's perfectly upvoteable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for your suggestion i have posted it as a answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ref: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5126

From ios 5.0 it does not retain the gesture recognizers when added to a view controller.

By making strong properties and connecting them to the gesture recognizers, you can ensure that they stay alive otherwise the app will crash.

Credit to Ray Wenderlich team member [Hollance](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=492).

Comment: So, if I don't create an outlet at all the recognizer will be released and the app will crash, am I correct? Was this fixed in iOS 6? Can I make the recognizer outlet weak for deployment target 6 or higher?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to a bug in UIKit. If you change that to weak, it will crash the app

Comment: I think this should not be the reason for this question.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addGestureRecognizer:

> Attaching a gesture recognizer to a view defines the scope of the represented gesture, causing it to receive touches hit-tested to that view and all of its subviews. The view establishes a **strong** reference to the gesture recognizer.